# Titanium scrollable view index

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium

My project is to list products with a views, then when click on a product i have to go to another page and re-list the products with scrollableview and target the clicked view to be displayed first (sorry for bad english):

Let's say this is my list (Grabbed from a collection) :

```
<Alloy>
<Window id="products" onClose="cleanup" title="All products" class="container" >
    <ScrollView dataCollection="list_products" dataTransform="parse_liste" layout='vertical' id="results" class="resultats">
        <View product_id="{ID}" 
            product_photo="{photo}" 
            product_name="{product_name}" lauyout='horizontal' class='heightAuto' width='Ti.UI.FILL' backgroundColor='#eee' bottom='1'>
            <ImageView touchEnabled="false" left='10' image='{photo}' />
            <View touchEnabled="false" layout='vertical' height='Ti.UI.SIZE'>
                <Label touchEnabled="false" left='100' class='nom' text='{product_name}' />
                <Label touchEnabled="false" left='100' class='nom' text='{product_price} €/h' />
            </View>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
    <ActivityIndicator color="white" id="activityIndicator" message="Chargement des candidats ..."/>
</Window>
```

When click on product (the controller) :

```
var products = Alloy.Collections.liste_recherche;
$.activityIndicator.show();
products.fetch({
    success:function(model,results){
        Alloy.Globals.results = results;
        $.activityIndicator.hide();
    }
});

//// CLICK ON A PRODUCT
$.list_products.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if( Alloy.Globals.results ){
        ///////// GO TO PRODUCT PAGE AND PASS ARGS
        var xpng = require('xpng');
        xpng.openWin(Alloy.CFG.nav, 'product', Alloy.Globals.products);
    } 
});
```

**The product page :**

```
var args = $.args;

function getProfil(){
    var products_array = [];    
    var c = ['gray','green','blue','red'];
   _.each(args, function(item, key, value){

        /* Créer la vue */
        var product_container = Ti.UI.createView({
            id:item.ID,
            layout:'vertical',
            backgroundColor:c[Math.floor(Math.random() * c.length)]
       });

        var product_image = Ti.UI.createImageView({ image : item.photo});
        var product_name = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: item.champs_candidat.nom
    });

    product_container.add(product_image);
    product_container.add(product_name);
    products_array.push(product_container);     
});

    var style = $.createStyle({
        classes: ['listeProfiles'],
        apiName: 'ScrollableView'
    });
    var product_scroller = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
        className: 'listeProfiles',
        views : products_array,
        showPagingControl:true
   });
   product_scroller.applyProperties(style);
   $.product_win.add(product_scroller);
}
```

Those codes works fine, just i want to display clicked view (from page A) first.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to capture which view was clicked on ScrollView click event:

```
$.list_products.addEventListener('click', function(e){
// e.source will give you the clicked view and will behave like $.VIEW_ID
// so you can access any property or method of the clicked view using e.source here

Ti.API.info("Clicked View ID = " + e.source.product_id);   

    if( Alloy.Globals.results ){
        ///////// GO TO PRODUCT PAGE AND PASS ARGS
        var xpng = require('xpng');
        xpng.openWin(Alloy.CFG.nav, 'product', Alloy.Globals.products);
    } 
});
```

As per your code, you have already disabled the touches of child-views of the view with this property ***product_id***, so the above modified click event code will be able to provide you the correct product ID of the clicked View inside the ScrollView.

Now:

1. You have the product_id of the view clicked.
2. Write code on your collection data to know the index of that
   product_id.
3. Use the index from step 2 to set this property [***currentPage***](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView-property-currentPage) of ScrollableView

Here is the summary of overall process:

1. Get the ***product_id*** of the clicked view using e.source
2. Use this ***product_id*** to know its ***index*** in data collection.
3. Finally, ***index*** from step 2 will be the value of ***currentPage*** property of ScrollableView. (it's your preference how you pass this ***index*** to product page.)

Comment: Hello Prashant Saini, thank you for help, i can get product_id, i just wonder how to get the index now from data collection? i tried :   
var index = _.findIndex(Alloy.Globals.results, { 'product_id': e.source.product_id }); but it throws me an error

Comment: Hello, i tested and it worked, thank you for your help.

Comment: Great you solved it.

Unfortunately, I could not write the code to get the index from collection as you did not post the collection outline. But I knew you would be able to solve it through my steps and it will help you understand things better than getting a complete answer (though StackOverFlow means exact answers..hehe).

Comment: I just made a for loop from Alloy.Globals.products to get the index (easy) but i'am curious to know how to get it from collection. For the collection outline, i created it from the "reste" library https://github.com/jasonkneen/RESTe

Comment: There are other ways to do it without index because index is only useful when you have ordered lists as index is depend on ordering.. e.g. if you have Item A, B, C, D in order 1, 2, 3, 4....then you can take advantage of index,..... but if you have A, B, C, D in order like 3, 1, 4, 2, then you will need to keep an extra key-value which you can use to compare...Think of them and try out (it will enhance your logic)....Good Luck!!!

Comment: You're in right may be using custom attribute is a solution